# Npm install in a docker container cannot find my custom registry

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose, dns

I am trying to build a react app on a node:alpine image using docker-compose. But when the time comes to `npm install` it doesn't work with the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://<myCustomRegistry>/packageName failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND <myCustomRegistry>
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-04-03T15_06_13_130Z-debug.log
```

`myCustomRegistry` is the name of my registry which I'm accessing via a vpn.

### What I tried:

- restarting the vpn
- changing the .npmrc
- adding a dns field in the docker-compose.yml file under the right service using my company's DNS, which would know the `myCustomRegistry`. I first thought it might come from the fact that the docker-compose dns could not know `myCustomRegistry`. I might have done it wrong this is still a possible hypothesis.
- setting an npm proxy (read doc, but didn't know what to do)

### Documents:

#### Dockerfile

```
# Builds the react app into 3 static files
FROM node:alpine as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm i && npm run build

# Copies those static files and serve them
FROM node:alpine
RUN yarn global add serve
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/build .
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["serve", "-p", "80", "-s", "."]
```

#### Docker-compose config file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  <... other services>
  front:
    build: ./front
    container_name: dobby_front
    ports: 
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - './front:/app'
      - '/app/node_modules'
    dns:
      - 10.128.103.16
      - 172.21.103.5
```

#### .npmrc

```
registry=https://<myCustomRegistry>
save-exact=true
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try these things:

1. Use a non-alpine Node image
2. Remove `dns` entry in docker-compose.yml and make sure the container has access to the internet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I decided to use a workaround. For anyone dealing with the same issue, this will solve you problem LOCALLY. Please make sure any remote servers you're working with are also configured this way.

As I understood, it is not currently possible to use a custom DNS in build using docker-compose, it is only used in run. Therefore, to pass on a custom DNS, you have to use a workaround and add it to the entire global config.

Go to `/etc/docker` and edit or create a JSON file `daemon.json` adding the following:

```
{
    "dns": ["<your custom remote dns address here>", "8.8.8.8"]
}
```

The restart docker and, using your VPN this should be good to go:)

Please note that this is a hack/workaround and in no way a good practice for everyone. It's not well scoped: affecting your whole docker scope instead of just the one of your app.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried using all variations of DNS servers in the daemon.json file, but it would not find the registry.

I tried using the IP address of the registry instead of the fully qualified domain name (url):

```
npm i <package-name> --registry http://<ip-address>
```

I then modified my .npmrc to use the IP instead of the URL and `npm i` worked.

```
registry=http://<ip-address>
```

I did not have to change DNS entries.

---

**EDIT**

I realised that the URL I provided did not have the domain name or TLD (e.g. .[company-name].com). Upon adding this to original URL and also modifying DNS entry as mentioned in the answer it worked:

```
from
registry=http://<machine-name> 
to
registry=http://<machine-name>.<company-name>.com
```